# Scala Play framework: Binding form parameters to hidden fields

Tags: playframework-2.0, scala-template

I am working with Play 2.0.4 and have the following form in my scala template.

```
@fieldGroup(field: Field, className: String = "field") = {
<div class="twipsies well @className">

    <a class="removeField btn danger pull-right">Remove Field</a>

    @inputText( // <=== I need a hidden input field here
        field("id")
    )

    @inputText(
        field("name"),
        '_label -> "Name",
        '_help -> "Use lower case, starts with an alphabet can contain numbers and underscores."
    )
}
```

I need a few hidden fields in my forms, how do I bind it to the server side **Form** component? I have seen a **@inputHidden** template helper in the github repository but it is not available in the stable release. How do I accomplish what I am looking for? Thanks.

Comment: Had a similar issue, just posted a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911393/how-to-hide-a-text-field-in-play-framework/26096702#26096702]

Comment: "Handling HTML input creation yourself" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728377/play-scala-form-helper-with-custom-html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Write it 'manually' as common HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value='@field("id").value' >
```

or use a way described in the [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaFormHelpers) in **Handling HTML input creation yourself** section.

Comment: I have used this already, what if I have nested form objects? This would work for Customer, how do I do it for Customer.orders?

Comment: I don't know your model or the way how do you manage the relations, so how can I guess?

Comment: Hi, the same worked for nested relations as well. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just want to add a little note you need a @ sign before field("id"). Final code should look

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value='@field("id").value' >

Answer (score 3):

Use raw HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="@field("id").name" value='@field("id").value' >
```