# How to hide a text field in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

How to hide a text field in play framework? For example how to hide this field:

```
@inputText(userProfileForm("name"), '_label -> "Name")
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This should work in all browsers:

```
@inputText(
    userProfileForm("name"),
    '_label -> "Name",
    'style -> "display: none"
)
```

Note that this only hides the field, not the label etc.

If you want to hide the label aswell, you can't do this with the default helpers.
You can however specify the input field yourself:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="@userProfileForm.data.get("name")" />
```

The `name` should be name of the field in your form (coincidentally `name` aswell in this case).
I haven't tested the `value` but it should work, maybe you'll need to strip the `"` around `name`.

If you do this, the hidden data will be sent, along with the other data in the form to the server.

**Edit:**
If the hidden value is empty, that means you didn't bind it to the form when calling the view. You can bind the name to the form like this in Java (I don't know Scala, but it's explained [in the Play Scala documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaForms)):

```
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("name","get the username here");

return ok(index.render(userProfileForm.bind(data));
```

Another option (which is cleaner in my opinion) is to simply pass the username as an argument to the view. The controller becomes:

```
return ok(index.render(userProfileForm, "username goes here"));
```

And in the view you can then simply do:

```
@(userProfileForm : Form[UserProfileForm])(name : String)

@helper.form(...){
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="@name" />
    //...
}
```

Comment: @PrasanthAR I updated my post with some code to show how you can hide the input (and label etc.) and still have the ability to sent the hidden data to the server. Is this what you meant?

Comment: ofcourse  and i really appreciate you and really thanx... i can't up the arrow on today becoz, my upvote are empty for today i must upvote the answer tommarrow...

Comment: @PrasanthAR No problem, don't forget to mark the answer as Accepted if this solved your problem ;) !

Comment: ok thanx... one more thing u r using the html code 
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="@userProfileForm.data.get("name")" />
@userProfileForm.data.get("name")" this can be work on there..

Comment: @PrasanthAR I have now tested the `value="@userProfileForm.data.get("name")"` and it works. If the value in the generated HTML is empty, please check my edit in my answer for what is probably causing it.

Comment: thanx.. this look gud and thanx... i got  it

Comment: just added a cleaner solution using a custom field constructor

Answer (score 5):

The `inputText` helper takes a varargs of `(Symbol, Any)`, which represent the html attributes. If you are using html5 you can just add the hidden attribute:

```
@inputText(userProfileForm("name"), '_label -> "Name", 'hidden -> "hidden")
```

normally the `hidden` attribute has no value, but I couldn't find any information about how to do this with the helpers. In Chrome at least it works like this as well.

**edit**:

btw, you can also just use html instead of the helper:

```
<input attribute=value hidden />
```

Comment: Can you please post the html, that this code generates for you?

Comment: @inputText(userProfileForm("name"), '_label -> "Name", 'hidden -> "hidden") this code am use but don't work

Comment: A am in new in play so i don't  know so much about that and really sorry about that and this is my entire code for hiding..in view.....<div id="user_pic"> @inputText(userProfileForm("name"), '_label -> "Name", 'hidden -> "hidden")@inputText(userProfileForm("status"), '_label -> "Status")</fieldset><div class="actions"><input type="submit">

Comment: When you load the page in your browser, right-click on the page and click "View Page Source". What does the code for the input look like?

Comment: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="user4" hidden="hidden">

Comment: <div class="clearfix  " id="name_field">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <div class="input">
        
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="user4" hidden="hidden">

        <span class="help-inline"></span>
        <span class="help-block">Required</span> 
    </div>
</div>

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is an old question, but i had a similar issue, i wanted to hide an inputText and still, handle it using the helpers.
The best and cleanest way to do it is to write your own helper adding a custom value to tell when to hide the element itself.
I came to a solution like this

my own field constructor

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)
@if(elements.args.contains('hideIt)){
    @elements.input
}else{
<div class="@if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">
    <div class="input">
        @elements.input
        <span class="errors">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</span>
        <span class="help">@elements.infos.mkString(", ")</span> 
    </div>
</div>
}
```

that i used in the view file like this:

```
@inputText(form("fieldName"),
'hidden -> "true",
'hideIt -> true
)
```

now you are done :)

Answer (score 2):

While it worked, I didn't like the hashmap version provided by @Aerus, preferring to use the statically typed forms when possible, so I came up with an alternative.

```
final UserProfileForm initial = new UserProfileForm("get the username here");
return ok(index.render(Form.form(UserProfileForm.class).fill(initial));
```

Then, in the profile, you can do as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="@userProfileForm("name").value" />
```